# Best way to populate an NSTableView with an Image column and some Text columns- MonoMac c#

Tags: c#, image, nstableview, monomac

I'm trying to populate an NSTableView with an Image column and some text columns.

At the moment I have populated a purely text columns NSTableView, using the method found in the NSTableView sample in the monomac samples, but I think it might be a big clunky and I'm not sure if I can use this to populate different column types cause it uses a List of NSStrings.

It's something like this:

```
NSTableColumn showIdColumn = myTableView.FindTableColumn(SHOWID);
showIdColumn.Bind("value",myContentArray,"arrangedObjects.showId",null);
/*
NSTableColumn titleColumn = myTableView.FindTableColumn(TITLE);
titleColumn.Bind("value", myContentArray, "arrangedObjects.title", null);
*/
NSTableColumn dateColumn = myTableView.FindTableColumn(SHOWDATE);
dateColumn.Bind("value", myContentArray, "arrangedObjects.showDate", null);

NSTableColumn comicsColumn = myTableView.FindTableColumn(SHOWCOMICS);
comicsColumn.Bind("value",myContentArray, "arrangedObjects.showComics", null);

foreach (DataRow row in dtShowList.Rows)
{
    DateTime d = (DateTime)row["showDate"];
    string strDate = d.ToString("ddd, MMM d @ htt");
    List<NSString> objects = new List<NSString> 
        {
            new NSString(row["showId"].ToString ()),
            new NSString(strDate),
            new NSString(row["showComics"].ToString())
            //new NSString(row[2].ToString()),
            //new NSString(row[3].ToString ())
        };
}

var dict = NSMutableDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects.ToArray(), Keys.ToArray());
myContentArray.AddObject(dict);
```

Any ideas?